# How can I save multiple records and ignore the empty records, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP. I want to save multiple records on my form. For example, say I have a 20 record table with one ID. When I enter 18 records, 2 are empty. Now, how to save the them while ignoring the empty records?

**I shorten the code to be 3 record.**

FORM code with 3 record:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="inputDate" class="inputDate  form-control" value="11/22/2013" name="tanggal">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?$id;?>">
<table>
<thead>
     <tr>
     <th>DO</th>
     <th>PO</th>
     <th>Nama Relasi</th>
     <th>Alamat</th>
     <th>Pcs</th>
     <th>Harga</th>
     <th>Keterangan</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="do" name="do[]" id="do" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="do" name="po[]" id="po" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="do2" name="address[]" id="alamat" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="do" name="pcs[]" id="pcs" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ket[]" id="ket" ></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="do" name="do[]" id="do" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="do" name="po[]" id="po" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="do2" name="address[]" id="alamat" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="do" name="pcs[]" id="pcs" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ket[]" id="ket" ></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="do" name="do[]" id="do" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="do" name="po[]" id="po" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="do2" name="address[]" id="alamat" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="do" name="pcs[]" id="pcs" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ket[]" id="ket" ></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class="text-right">
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button><button type="reset">Delete</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

and PHP code:

```
<?
        include "dbase.php";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

            $do = $_POST['do'][$i];
            $po = $_POST['po'][$i];
            $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
            $address = $_POST['address'][$i];
            $pcs = $_POST['pcs'][$i];
            $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
            $ket = $_POST['ket'][$i];

            $query  = "SELECT max(id) FROM table1 ";
            $ids=mysql_query($query);
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($ids);
            $row[0]++;
            $norest=sprintf("%04d",$row[0]);

            $format = DO14;

            $id = $format.$norest; 
            $date = $_POST['tanggal'];

            $SQL = "INSERT INTO table1 (id,date,do,po,name,address,pcs,price,ket) VALUES ('$id','$date','$do','$po','$name','$address','$pcs','$price','$ket')";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL, $connect);

            if ($result) {
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><h5><b>Record save...</b></h5></div>";
                            }
                else {
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h5><b>Failure..</b></h5></div>";
                }

            }
        }
        ?>
```

nothing happens with the code above. can anybody help me?

Comment: This is too broad/unclear what exactly you are asking. How does your form look like? What did you already try? Can't you use array syntax for names (e.g. `name="optionalfield[]"`) and iterate over those in PHP, selecting the non empty ones for update?

Comment: your code is perfect for sql injection... please re-think your approach.

Comment: @jakub yap... i know that, it just sample.. but I need a solution to the case above

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of your PHP script and show the results here?

Comment: array(0) { } 

and

[session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\AppServ\www\sb-admin\inkirim.php:2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without an example of code (if you update the question I can update my answer), but if you have a form with 20 inputs using an array for the name `<input type="text" name="records[]" id="record-1" />` then you can iterate through `$_POST['records']` on submit.

```
foreach($_POST['records'] as $record) {
  if(!empty($record)) {
    // Insert record here
  }
}
```

`if(!empty($records))` can be replaced with `if($records)` or `if($records != null)` depending on your specific needs of what an "empty" record is.

Comment: This is tricky as `empty` evaluates all _falsey_ values to false (and not only empty ones)

Comment: @kingkero good point, I made a note of this below.  It really depends on the scenario for which conditional you should use.

Comment: @SamSullivan, Sir, I have update my Question. so please update your answer too. thanks before for all your help.